# Replace varchar length with a constant macro

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Normally we would define varchar in SQL Server like this.

In store procedure, the input varaible @name will be declared as

```
@name varchar(32);
```

However, "32" is hard coded. Other developer would use 24, 64 or something else in some other store procedure.

It is hard to maintain.

Is there some way to write like this?

```
@name varchar(VAR_NAME_LENGTH);
```

VAR_NAME_LENGTH is defined somewhere globally, like C

```
#define VAR_NAME_LENGTH 32
```

Then all the developer could stick to use this macro instead of hard code 32.

Not sure if this is possible in SQL Server.

Or other good idea?

Note: SQL Server version is 2008 SP2.

Comment: I don't know whether or not it is a good idea, but it isn't possible, unless you define all your tables using dynamic SQL.

Comment: you can define types in SQL Server but I don't use them as they make TSQL harder to read.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, It is possible by using [user-defined data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms175007.aspx). But, in practice it is not that useful, because you can't easily change the definition of the custom type.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov . . . I was thinking that the OP also wanted to be able to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using [user-defined data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms175007.aspx). But, in practice it is not that useful, because you can't easily change the definition of the custom type.

See an article [Bad habits to kick : using alias types](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-alias-types) by Aaron Bertrand for more details.

In the comments to that article Alexander Kuznetsov said:

> Actually we badly need the ability to define a type once and use it
> many times. To accomplish that, I use macros and run a standard C++
> preprocessor against all my SQL code to expand them.
>
> For example, to convert in my include file I used to define
>
> ```
> #define MAX_VARCHAR VARCHAR(8000)
> ```
>
> In my code, I can write this all over my system:
>
> ```
> [Comments] MAX_VARCHAR,
> ```
>
> which will expand to
>
> ```
> [Comments] VARCHAR(8000),
> ```
>
> Converting to 2005, I replaced the macro with:
>
> ```
> #define MAX_VARCHAR VARCHAR(MAX)
> ```
>
> and let SQL Compare take care of all the details.

So, if you have all your database objects scripted (which is good to have in any case), then it becomes a matter of running the extra step of preprocessor before running the final T-SQL scripts to create the database.